# Cloning an existing Android Studio project

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I have an existing Android Studio project managed under git (via Bitbucket). I cloned this project so that I could work on it on another computer. After cloning I import the project to Android Studio on the new computer using the following process starting at the "Welcome to Android Studio"

- select "Import Project (Gradle, Eclipse ADT etc...)
- Import Project from External Model (Android Gradle)

On Android Studio in the cloned computer there is no neat Project structure (manifests, java, res etc...) but it's all under the source folder in different places. Is there any way to get it set up like it is on Android Studio on the original computer?

Here is the .gitignore (it was set up automatically by Android Studio when I first set up the repo.

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/caches
/.idea/libraries
/.idea/modules.xml
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/navEditor.xml
/.idea/assetWizardSettings.xml
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
```

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated!

**Extra info**

Here is the original Android Studio project structure:
[image]

Here is the new Android Studio project structure:
[image]

** More info **
After selecting "Android" the project is still not grouped as in the initial Android Studio
[image]

Comment: Would you please share the snapshot of top level project structure from both bitbucket and from the computer where you cloned and imported.

Comment: .gitignore looks fine.

Comment: By the way did you choose build.gradle while importing the project into android studio?

Comment: Above project structure click on the project and switch it to android then it will display the same project structure like on your old computer.

Comment: Pls, Try this my solution